# Bootstrap 3 img-responsive breaks after applying css rotate

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

After rotating an image 90degrees inside an modal, the img-responsive is not working anymore. The image height goes beyond the modal height.

```js
function rotate(){
    var angle = ($('#testImg').data('angle') + 90) || 90;
    $('#testImg').css({'transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});
    $('#testImg').data('angle', angle);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.modal').modal('show');
})
```

```css
.modal {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img id="testImg" class="img-responsive" src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/LYiEQH6.jpg">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="rotate()"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There isnt really any custom css at all. Only using the defaults from bootstrap. Edited the modal style tho, but that doesnt seem to change anything.

Comment: Updated the code snippet. Click the blue button to rotate the image and see the problem.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain on this (hence not posting it as an answer) but just because you have rotated the image the width is still the width, so when you rotate it the image won't fill the area across (what was the height) because it is just a transformation, it isn't actually rotating the image.

Comment: I understand your point neo, but you have another solution to rotate the image other than using css?

Comment: What are you expecting? You've explained the problem but not said what your ideal solution is

Comment: The image should adjust its size to fit within the modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this example: https://jsbin.com/veranak/edit?html,css,js,output it's not a problem of the modal.

The height of the responsive image container is relative to the width and height of the image. The css transform property rotate the image, but doesn't affect the size of its container (nor the size of the image, it just rotates it).

1) you can try adding the scrollbar to the .modal-body element instead of .modal

```
.modal-body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

2) this article may help you find a more elegant solution: http://kizu.ru/en/fun/rotated-text/

jsbin code below

html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">
        <img id="testImg" class="img-responsive" src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/LYiEQH6.jpg">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="rotate()"></button>
</div>
```

css:

```
.image {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

javascript:

```
function rotate(){
    var angle = ($('#testImg').data('angle') + 90) || 90;
    $('#testImg').css({'transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});
    $('#testImg').data('angle', angle);
}
```